# Automatically add package declaration after refreshing folder (package) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I am using an external tool that automatically generates some Java classes inside my Java project. I need to frequently use this tool, which means it frequently generates new classes inside the project.

I am using Eclipse for development. To include new classes inside my project, I refresh the package and it is done, but I have to use eclipse short-cut (i.e., quick tips) to include the package declaration to **each of the new classes**. Repeating the same procedure many times is quite tedious.

Do you know whether Eclipse can automatically add package declaration to each of the new classes (created outside of Eclipse) when loading them inside Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse can't do that , you need to do it from the tool. If your tool can generate java classes , it should be able  add the package name as well

Comment: Out of curiosity, what tool are you talking about? It may be able to do this for you. If not, have you considered putting them in the package it declares them as? (Classes with no package declaration are at the root level.)

Comment: I am using antlr-4.5. I know there is an eclipse plugin which can generate classes with package name, how ever this plugin works only with antlr.4.4, I couldn't make it work with 4.5 version @CaptainMan

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment that this would preferably be done by the tool, or possibly a script.

However, if you really want to do this from Eclipse, I found a quite wierd, but working workaround:

- Switch to *hierarchical* package presentation:

[image: Hierarchical package presentation]

- Use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> on the root package to rename the package to something like *tmp*. Uncheck *Update reference* (I assume you don't have references since you don't even have package declarations) and check *Rename subpackages*. Now Eclipse should have renamed the root package, and fixed the imports in the process.

[image]

- After this, all I needed to do was to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> to undo the refactor. Eclipse renames the package back, but also keeps the package declarations.

Comment: It works in this way, it adds/updates the package declarations ... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on a comment by OP on the question

> I am using antlr-4.5.

So I found a more specific solution, from [ANTLR Tool Command Line Options](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/ANTLR+Tool+Command+Line+Options):

> `-package ___` specify a package/namespace for the generated code

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a eclipse macro you can try [Practically Macro](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/practically-macro) for this purpose.

:)

Answer (score 0):

If your newly generated class is not in the same directory of the referencing class, you will either have to explicitly import the package which contains that class OR you may do like following in your code to ignore the import:

```
com.mypacakge.MynewClass = new com.mypacakge.MyNewClass();
```

But I honestly don't know if Eclipse can automaticly do the import for you.